# Se acumula el iterador java

Tags: java

Quiero hacer un programa que agregue elementos tipo int a una lista y con ayuda de un iterador sume los elementos que cumplen ciertas características. El problema está en que cuando doy varias condiciones, los resultados se acumulan. Ejemplo: agrego 1 2 3 4 5 a la lista y pongo dos condiciones, la primera es que sume los que son divisibles por 2 y la segunda los que son divisibles por 3; así el resultado sería 6 en la condición uno y 3 en la condición dos. Pero con este error, me da como resultado 6 en la primera y en la segunda 9 porque los resultados los acumula.
Este es mi codigo, el ejemplo sería ingresando:
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
M 1
M 2
M 3
A 5
M 6
E

Nótese que las instrucciones son ingresadas por teclado mediante "M", "A" y "E"

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> lista = new LinkedList<>();
        Iterator<Integer> iterador;
        int x, y, s = 0, t;

        String n = "jjkb";
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!n.equals("E")) {
            n = entrada.next();

            if (n.equals("A")) {
                x = entrada.nextInt();
                lista.add(x);

            }

            if (n.equals("M")) {
                y = entrada.nextInt();
                iterador = lista.listIterator();
                while (iterador.hasNext()) {
                    t = iterador.next();
                    if (t % y == 0) {
                        s += t;

                    }

                }
                System.out.println(s);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Duban, tienes que mostrar tu codigo si quieres ayuda. De lo contrario solo adivinaríamos la respuesta.

Comment: @Duban Zuluaga Como te indica Einer debes de tener en una pregunta [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Asumo que A es añadir, M es calcular la suma y E es terminar:

Lo que te falta es reiniciar la variable `s` después de mostrarla por pantalla:

```
    if (n.equals("M")) {
        y = entrada.nextInt();
        iterador = lista.listIterator(); //<-- Inicializas el iterador
        s=0; // <-- inicializas el acumulador
        while (iterador.hasNext()) {
            t = iterador.next();
            if (t % y == 0) {
                s += t;

            }

        }
        System.out.println(s);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, segun tu cadena de entrada, estas haciendo que la primera vez que llega la lista en la linea: 
if (n.equals("M")) 
a lista contiene los valores [1,2,3,4]
y el valor de t es 1
por lo que el resultado de de la primera ejecucion del 
System.out.println(s); s vale la suma de 1+2+3+4 -- 10.

al recoger el siguiente valor y ser otra  M, volera a entrar con la misma lista
LinkedList lista =  [1,2,3,4]
pero esta vez sacas aquellos que modulo con 2 es 0, por lo que sumara a s los valores que cumplan esto.
[2 y 4]
como no reiniciaste s= 10 + 2+4.

A la siguiente pasada, la lista sigue igual  LinkedList lista =  [1,2,3,4]
esta vez vamos a ejecutar el obtener los divisibles de 3, por lo que solo aparece el [3].
al no haber reiniciado s: s= 16+3

ahora añadiras el 5 a la lista, por que viene precedido de la letra A.
 LinkedList lista =  [1,2,3,4,5]

y luego quieres calcular cual es divisible por 6, logicamente ninguno.
asique no se suma nada a s.

pero vuelve a imprimir en pantalla el valor de s.
s=19.

tienes que revisar:
1º, si quieres calcular la lista y luego los divisores en una misma entrada, los dividiria en dos Arrays difentes:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> lista = new LinkedList<>();
    Iterator<Integer> iterador;
    int x, y, s = 0, t;
    List<Integer> divisores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String n = "jjkb";
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!n.equals("E")) {
        n = entrada.next();
        if (n.equals("A")) {
            x = entrada.nextInt();
            lista.add(x);
        } else if (n.equals("M")) {
            divisores.add(entrada.nextInt());
        }

    }
    for (Integer integer : divisores) {
        s = 0;
        iterador = lista.listIterator();
        while (iterador.hasNext()) {
            t = iterador.next();
            if (t % integer == 0) {
                s += t;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Fijate que hemos sacado el recorrido por los valores: por un lado la lista valores, con [1,2,3,4,5] y por otro la lista divisores que contendra [1,2,3,6]

por lo que te dara 4 salidas, la primera de evaluar con 1-->15, al evaluar con 2-->6, y al evaluar con el 3-->3, la ultima salida es al terminar con el 6-->0.

Si necesitas ajustar creo que ya con el modo debug te sera sencillo a tus necesidades.

Un saludo.